# Using one view but multiple tags in my template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am stumped and I'm sure it's simple but I'm looking to have this one view generating nine different integers in cells. I am not sure best way to get these to be different. As of now they are all the same. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**VIEW**

```
def randums(request):
    lower = 10**(9-1)
    upper = 10**9 - 1
    result = random.randint(lower, upper)
    context = {'result': result}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)


def generate_numbers(randums):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        context = generate_numbers()
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"><tbody>
        <tr><td>{{ result }}</td><td>{{ result }}</td><td>{{ result }}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{ result }}</td><td>{{ result }}</td><td>{{ result }}</td></tr>
        <tr><td>{{ result }}</td><td>{{ result }}</td><td>{{ result }}</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>

    <button type="submit" class="rndbtn btn btn-primary btn-large">Random Change</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list and add to it the 9 random numbers:

```
def randums(request):
    lower = 10**(9-1)
    upper = 10**9 - 1
    result = []
    for x in range(0, 9):
        result.append(random.randint(lower, upper))
    context = {'result': result}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and in you view loop over the result

Comment: Thanks @almalki :) I knew I was over looking something simple